# Python: Cython build issues

Tags: python, visual-c++, python-2.7, visual-studio-2013, cython

I have been having many issues building Cython in my virtual machine in windows, I had no problems in OSX and its really starting to frustrate me...

Long story short I am trying to build/install the following libraries:
- Cython-0.19.2
- cython-hidapi
- pycrypto-2.6.1

Lets start with Cython...

`>>setup.py clean install`

```
running clean
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'Cython.Compiler.Code' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`
```

This can be rectified by: `SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS120COMNTOOLS%` **but is not permanent, how can I make this permanent?**

Then run `>>setup.py clean install` again:

```
running clean
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'Cython.Compiler.Code' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Cython
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Cython\Compiler
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /TcCython\Compiler\Code.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Cython\Compiler\Code.obj
Code.c
c:\python27\include\pymath.h(22) : warning C4273: 'round' : inconsistent dll linkage
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(51
6) : see previous definition of 'round'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:initCode build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Cython\Compiler\Code.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\Cython\Compiler\Code.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Cython\Compiler\Code.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Cython\Compiler\Code.pyd.manifest
Code.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'initCode' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Cython\Compiler\Code.lib an
d object build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Cython\Compiler\Code.exp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\mt.exe -nologo -manifest build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Cython\Compiler\Code.pyd.manifest -outputresource:build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\Cython\Compiler\Code.pyd;2
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Cython\Compiler\Code.pyd.manifest : general error c1010070: Failed to load and parse the manifest. The system cannot find the file specified.
error: command 'mt.exe' failed with exit status 31
```

Nothing I do seems to rectify this second issue, I have VS2013 installed. Im sure this all can be fixed in my environment variable %PATH%... but im not sure what is wrong with them:

> c:\altera\12.1sp1\modelsim_ase\win32aloem;C:\Python27;C:\WINNT\system32;C:\WINNT;C:\WINNT\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin;SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS120COMNTOOLS%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include

**EDIT:**

Still looking for permanent fix for first issue.

**Fix For 2nd problem:**
Microsoft Security Essentials is locking the manifest file, adding your project directories to its excluded directories fix the issue.

**New issue:**
When building Cython-HIDAPI:

```
running clean
removing 'build\temp.win-amd64-2.7' (and everything under it)
removing 'build'
running install
running build
running build_ext
skipping 'hid.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'hid' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tchid.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hid.obj
hid.c
c:\python27\include\pymath.h(22) : warning C4273: 'round' : inconsistent dll linkage
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(516) : see previous definition of 'round'
hid.c(801) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of dataC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tchid-libus
b.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hid-libusb.obj
hid-libusb.c
hid-libusb.c(34) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory
error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```

**Fixed by Modifying the C file to check for win vs linux headers...**

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
    /* Unix */
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <sys/ioctl.h>
    #include <sys/utsname.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
#endif
```

**Most of the remaining issues where fixed in this manner**

**Will post a new question for the last problem I am having since this one is getting cluttered, Ill leave this up for anyone else that may have this problem in the future**